# Passing array with data to Google Chart Tools

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-visualization

I am trying to draw a chart using Google Chart Tools.

```
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'Month');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Money');
    data.addRows([
        [<%= @months %>, <%= @money %>] 
        ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Title'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_2'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

@months and @money are arrays. Unfortunately, probably I can't pass an array in this way, because the chart does not show up. What is the right dealing with this kind of situation?

**UPDATE**

Ok, I've use Gon and setCell function in for loop and it works

Answer (score 0):

Use json. The `respond_to` block can be used for this. Return the json hash containing the array of data values.

```
def months_monies
  respond_to |format|
    format.json {render :json => @post}
    # The post is a Ruby hash that gets converted into json string
    format.html #months_monies.html.erb
  end
end
```

Consider an example where the `@post` variable is, say `{:a => {"January" => 1000}, :b => {"April" => 1222}}`

This can be accessed from the javascript block by making an AJAX call to `http://localhost:3000/months_monies.json`

Example using jQuery:

```
$.get("http://localhost:3000/controller/months_monies.json",function(post){
  post.a.January # => 1000
  post.b.April   # => 1222
});
```

If the `@post` variable were an array (which in your case might most possibly be the case), the method is almost similar. Say `@post = [{'january' => 1000}, {'february' => 1111}]`

Then you would use `post[0].january` and `post[1].february` to get the values in the `$.get` block.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can I use [Gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) instead of JSON? If, yes I can use my @post as gon.post in chart code, but Is there any possibility to pass and use whole array, without referencing to single elements of array?

Comment: Try using the `Gon` module. Haven't used it anytime and so, cannot be sure. I've used a hash in the example so that it will be a clear how the data representation gets converted. You can pass the entire array. `@post = {@months => [...], @money => [...]}` will get converted into this json object: `{'months' : [...], 'money' : [...]}`

Comment: If you can show a sample of the data, I will add it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

In my SO question I show a working example of passing a ruby array to Google chart api. (My problem has to do with specifying a missing/null series value in Ruby which does not seem to affect your problem.)

[using google chart api in rails app - how specify a null (missing) value in a series when using arrayToDataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890401/using-google-chart-api-in-rails-app-how-specify-a-null-missing-value-in-a-se)