# Pull datasets from DB and manipulate into separate arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, google-visualization

My DB has four fields, date:date, morning:integer, afternoon:integer, evening:integer.

Google charts needs the data split into one array per dataset (example below).  What's the best way to do this?

```
  ['Day',     'Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening'],
  ['06/27/13',  1000,       400           234],
  ['06/28/13',  1170,       460           275],
  ['06/29/13',  660,        1120          377],
  ['06/30/13',  1030,       540           934]
```

I've tried this without much luck:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  <% @todo.each do |t| %>
  ['Day',                                   'Morning',        'Afternoon',        'Evening'],
  [<%= t.date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") %>,  <%= t.morning %>, <%= t.afternoon %>, <%= t.evening %>]
  <% end %>
]);
```

Comment: you need array of arrays, right?

Comment: @Muntasim oh, I think so.  Not sure how to implement though.

Comment: Can you link google docs for this chart?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel No, I'm using an SQL database.

Comment: @dresdin you write "Google charts needs the data" so wtf? Can you link the docs for the chart you try to create?

Answer (score 0):

```
data = @todo.inject([['Day','Morning','Afternoon','Evening']]) do |ar, t|
  ar << [t.strftime("%m/%d/%y"), t.morning, t.afternoon, t.evening]
end
```

then send `data` to google chart

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<%= data.to_json%>);
```

Comment: Should've worked.  But the page doesn't render the chart.  When I hardcode the exact same data (copied from the console) into the html.erb, it works fine.  There's something going on with passing the <%= data %> variable into Google Charts.

Comment: try to inspect the js log using console.log. Rails part seems okay.

Here is another post describing the same thing:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890401/using-google-chart-api-in-rails-app-how-specify-a-null-missing-value-in-a-se

Comment: Found the issue.  For whatever reason my quotes were converting to &quot;.  Just had to add ".to_json.html_safe" and it works perfectly.